# CQLC: Go Cassandra query returning page token for boundary limit?

Tags: go, cassandra, cql, gocql

In my Cassandra database for a particular query, I have 8 records, and I am using GoLang [relops/cqlc](https://github.com/relops/cqlc) library.

When I query with limit = 8, it returns 8 records with a PageState which is to be used as page token for the next set of results. I don't think it should have returned that PageState. And also as expected when I query again with that page_token and the same query parameters, it returns no data.

The same thing does not happen if I increase the limit by one more, say 9.

Did someone else face a similar issue? Any hints as to what might be the issue?

Comment: I'm using gocql for first time so not really sure what the issue is, but looks like CQLC is just a wrapper around gocql? https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/f5cee644705e9593c342bfabe667720580a5289f/conn.go#L783.  Is page state handling specified by the cql spec and gocql handling of it doesn't comply with the specification? or is gocql handling of it something you found unintuitive?

Comment: @dm03514 Does cassandra return page token for boundary limit cases?